# Clarification for me to understand this Concept Better

Tags: javascript

```
// Values Set Outside of Eventhandler
const guessBtn = document.querySelector('#guess-btn');
const guessInput = document.querySelector('#guess-input');

//Working Eventhandler
guessBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  parseInt(guessInput.value);
});

// Me trying to use a fat arrow function inside addEventHandler
guessBtn = addEventListener(
  'click', 
  let guess = () => parseInt(guessInput.value)
);
```

I want to understand this better, but here is what I take from what I have read. The fat arrow function in //Me Trying isn't executing either because it's written incorrectly, or if it is written correctly it's unable to pull in the value from outside of itself (this) lexical scope, due to the fact that the fat arrow function does not pull in the //Const guess-input defined outside of the scope of the function. I am learning Java-script and would like to use best practices as I learn and try to simplify my code from tutorials with ES6 syntax when possible.

Comment: is your problem that you have `guessBtn = addEventListener` instead of `guessBtn.addEventListener`?

Comment: Also `let guess` inside the arguments to a function call is a syntax error. Did you mean `() => { let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value); }`

Comment: You should really make the title of your question specific as to what you are asking for. Think of others following in your footsteps, what terms they'd Google on - and use that for your title.

Comment: I will be sure to be more specific next time, I was unsure if using an arrow function in a eventhandler was even possible. I was under the impression that the "this" aspect to the arrow function wasn't allowing me to use the variable guessInput. I got it to work doing this block. `guessBtn.addEventListener('click', (guessEvent) => {
  let guess = parseInt(guessInput.value)` I named the parameter to understand it better. thank you for your help
  console.log(guess);

Comment: The tutorial is using the function keyword to execute the event-listener, I am trying to get use to refactoring the code in ES6 format to practice and understand the arrow functions and ternary operators better and where I can use them as I learn. Took me all morning but I learned a lot from it.